# Setting random Timer intervals in VB

Tags: vb.net, random, timer, intervals

My goal is to make code that will beep randomly anywhere from 1 to 30 seconds apart. Here is my code so far:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Console.Beep()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
End Class
```

This beeps every one second. Now, I want to change the `Timer` Interval so that it will beep randomly between 1 and 30 seconds. Maybe later I will add options for the user to define the bounds, but for now, 1 and 30 are good numbers. I just don't know how to apply a random number to my Timer Interval.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Interval` on every `Tick`:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private p_oRandom As Random

  Private Const INTERVAL_MIN_SEC As Integer = 1
  Private Const INTERVAL_MAX_SEC As Integer = 30

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    p_oRandom = New Random
  End Sub

  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles _
                                                                      Timer1.Tick
    Console.Beep()
    Timer1.Interval = p_oRandom.Next(INTERVAL_MIN_SEC, INTERVAL_MAX_SEC) * 1000
  End Sub

End Class
```