# VB.net - Set timer interval between two user defined values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, timer

very new to programming and stackoverflow.
In vb.net, currently I have the timer interval set to a inserted value in a text box.
I would like to have two text boxes with values (ex. 30000 and 40000) and the timer interval be set to a random number between those two values (ex. between 30 and 40 seconds). Would like to have this number be recalculated each time the timer ticks. Thank you.

The closest thing I could find was : [Setting random Timer intervals in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935427/setting-random-timer-intervals-in-vb) but it did not deal with user defined values.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work better for you?

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Timers
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents time As New Timer
    Private randNum As New System.Random

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.TextBox1.Text = "30000"
        Me.TextBox2.Text = "40000"
        time.Interval = 1000 ' enable timer when form loads
        time.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub time_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles time.Elapsed
        ' this code (below) assumes valid data against TextBox1 and TextBox2
        time.Interval = randNum.Next(CInt(Me.TextBox1.Text), CInt(Me.TextBox2.Text))
        Debug.WriteLine(time.Interval.ToString)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: All I needed to add was:
timer1.Interval = randNum.Next(CInt(TextBox1.Text), CInt(TextBox2.Text))

Also,
Debug.WriteLine(Timer1.Interval.ToString) helped to confirm that it works.
Thanks a bunch! 
( :

Answer (score 0):

In your timer code...  Add something similar to this..

```
Dim randNum As New System.Random
Debug.WriteLine(randNum.Next(30, 40).ToString)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but what I am looking for is to have 2 text boxes where the user enters values into, and to have the timer interval as a random number in between those 2 values.